# How to pass nextProps to mapped array

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

The following code renders a like object when its clicked.

So when  `console.log(nextProps.myPosts)` exectues

it goes from this

*Likes(95)*

[image]

to this

*Likes(96*)

[image]

Currently im getting the like counts like

`myLikes={post.Likes.length}`

And its not showing the reflected change on the ui, so what should i change so it can reflect the updated prop ?

**Posts.js**

```
class Posts extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
    loading: true,
    isEditing: false, 
    // likes:[]
  }
  componentWillMount(){
     this.props.GetPosts();

    this.setState({
      loading:false
    })

  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    let hasNewLike = true ;
    if(prevState.posts && prevState.posts.length) {
      for(let index=0; index < nextProps.myPosts.length; index++) {
      if(nextProps.myPosts[index].Likes.length != 
       prevState.posts[index].Likes.length) {
         hasNewLike = false;

      }
    }

   this.setState({posts: nextProps.myPosts});  // here we are updating the posts state if redux state has updated value of likes

  console.log(nextProps.myPosts) 
 }

  render() {
    const {loading} = this.state;
    const { myPosts} = this.props
    if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return (<Redirect to='/signIn' />);
    }
    if(loading){
      return "loading..."
    }
    return (
      <div className="App" style={Styles.wrapper}>
        <h1> Posts </h1>
        <PostList posts={this.state.posts}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuthenticated,
  myPosts: state.post.posts,


})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, state) => ({
  GetPosts: () => dispatch( GetPosts())
});
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Posts));
```

**PostList.js**

```
class PostList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            title: '',

        }
    } 
    // Return a new function. Otherwise the DeletePost action will be dispatch each
     // time the Component rerenders.
    removePost = (id) => () => {
        this.props.DeletePost(id);
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            title: e.target.value
        })
    }
    formEditing = (id) => ()=> {;
        this.props.EditChange(id);
    }

    render(){
        const {posts} = this.props;
        return (
          <div>
            {posts.map(post => (

              <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                <PostItem
                  myLikes={post.Likes.length} // right here
                  myTitle={this.state.title}
                  editChange={this.onChange}
                  editForm={this.formEditing}
                  isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id}
                  removePost={this.removePost}
                  {...post}

                />
              </Paper>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,
    // ourLikes: state.post.likes // reducer likes 
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // pass creds which can be called anything, but i just call it credentials but it should be called something more 
    // specific.
    EditChange: (id) => dispatch(EditChange(id)),
    UpdatePost: (creds) => dispatch(UpdatePost(creds)),
    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id)),
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
    DeletePost: (id) => dispatch(DeletePost(id))
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostList);
```

**reducer**

```
const initialState = {
    post: [],
    postError: null,
    posts:[],
    isEditing:false,
    isEditingId:null,
    likes:[],
    someLike:[],
    postId:null
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case GET_POSTS:
    console.log(action.data)

        return {
            ...state, 
            posts: action.data, // maps posts fine,


    }
    case ADD_LIKE:
        const newState = {...state};  // here I am trying to shallow  copy the existing state;
        const existingLikesOfPost = newState.posts.find(post => post.id == action.id).Likes;
        newState.posts.find(post => post.id == action.id).Likes = [...existingLikesOfPost, action.newLikeObject]; // using this approach I got some code duplication so I suggested the first approach of using **push** method of array.
        return newState
```

**Like component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCoffee, faAdjust } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {  postLike} from '../actions/';
class Like extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            likes: null,
            heart: false
        }
    }

    //  passes post id thats stored in PostItem.js
    clickLike = (id) => {
        this.props.postLike(id);
        // toggles between css class
        this.setState({
            heart: !this.state.heart
        })
    }
    render(){
       return(
            <div style={{float:'right', fontSize: '1.5em', color:'tomato'}} >
            <i style={{ marginRight: '140px'}} className={this.state.heart ? 'fa fa-heart':'fa fa-heart-o' }>
                    <span style={{ marginLeft: '6px'}}>
                        <a href="#" onClick={() =>this.clickLike(this.props.like)}>Like</a>   

                    </span>
                    {/* gets the like counts */}
                    <span style={{ marginLeft: '7px'}} >{this.props.likes}  </span>  

                </i>
            </div>       
       )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,
    // myLikes: state.post.likes
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({

    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id))
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Like);
```

**PostItem.js**

```
.....
class PostItem extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            disabled: false,

        }
    }


    onUpdate = (id, title) => () => {
        // we need the id so expres knows what post to update, and the title being that only editing the title. 
        if(this.props.myTitle !== null){
            const creds = {
                id, title
            }
            this.props.UpdatePost(creds); 
        }
    }

    render(){
        const {title, id, userId, removePost, createdAt, post_content, username, editForm, isEditing, editChange, myTitle, postUpdate, Likes, clickLike, myLikes} = this.props
        return(
            <div>
                   <Typography variant="h6" component="h3">
                   {/* if else teneray operator */}
                   {isEditing ? (
                          <Editable editField={myTitle ? myTitle : title} editChange={editChange}/>
                   ): (
                       <div>
                           {title}
                       </div>    
                   )}         
                   </Typography>
                   <Typography  component={'span'} variant={'body2'}>
                       {post_content}
                       <h5>by: {username} </h5>
                       {/*  component span cancels out the cant be a decedent of error */}
                       <Typography  component={'span'} variant={'body2'} color="textSecondary">{moment(createdAt).calendar()}</Typography>
                      {/* gets like counts */}
                       <Like like={id} likes={myLikes} /> 
                   </Typography>
                   {!isEditing ? (
                       <Button variant="outlined" type="submit" onClick={editForm(id)}>
                           Edit
                       </Button>
                   ):(     
                       // pass id, and myTitle which as we remember myTitle is the new value when updating the title
                        <div>
                            <Button 
                                disabled={myTitle.length <= 3}
                                variant="outlined" 
                                onClick={this.onUpdate(id, myTitle)}>
                                Update
                            </Button>
                            <Button 
                                variant="outlined" 
                                style={{marginLeft: '0.7%'}}
                                onClick={editForm(null)}>
                                Close
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                   )}
                   {!isEditing && (
                    <Button
                        style={{marginLeft: '0.7%'}}
                        variant="outlined"
                        color="primary"
                        type="submit"
                        onClick={removePost(id)}>
                        Remove
                    </Button>
                    )}
           </div>
       )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,

})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // pass creds which can be called anything, but i just call it credentials but it should be called something more 
    // specific.
    UpdatePost: (creds) => dispatch(UpdatePost(creds)),
    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id)),

    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostItem);
```

Comment: Hi @Amber Wallen. Let me know if my understanding is correct so I can better provide you with an answer. The redux store has the updated like value, but that is not being reflected in your component correct?

Comment: ill share the reducer one sec.

Comment: let me know if you need more information. thx.

Comment: So yes the redux store  have the updated value but its not being reflected in component, correct.

Comment: Wallen. Thank you for providing that. I think I might have found a solution for your problem. Let me know if that makes sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

Following what you wrote, shouldn't hasNewLike be set to true if the comparison of the two lengths are not equal? Meaning that it has a new like? :)

That way we can update the component state and pass that into your child PostList component.

```
  if(nextProps.myPosts[index].Likes.length != 
   prevState.posts[index].Likes.length) {
     hasNewLike = true;
  }
```

Comment: about to try it out.

Comment: Great! Also make sure to set hasNewLike = false for the initial declaration of the variable.

Comment: i think i made a mistake. I actually commented out the hasnewLike if statement, i don't need it. However the issue persists. let me make an edit to the code

Comment: sorry about that :(

Comment: the count doesn't show. with or wiithout the (hasnewLike) if statement

Comment: `myLikes={post.Likes.length} ` does this needs to be changed ?

Comment: No worries Amber! sorry for the late reply. I think your mark-up for myLikes={post.likes.length} looks fine. It is showing an initlal like count correct? Let me take a look at your updated code above.

Comment: yes it does show an initial value, and only on refresh do i see the updated value.

Comment: Hmm, you know based on the code you have provided, I don't see what could be wrong. If you have this project on github or something, I'd be happy to branch off it and help you find a solution. With the information you have provided I cannot deduce anything wrong. :(

Comment: What would happen if i moved the componentWillReceiveProps logic to the PostList.js component

Comment: and u no thats fine, i will end up figuring it out, but i would need some sorta hint. on where to focus on. the back end and the reducer works, all it does it just does not update the like count value.

Comment: Just so you know, the posts are being called from an action, and being fetched by reducer props posts, and im making it into a state. Could it be something to the effect that redux props being immutable even though i converted the props to a state ?

Comment: `this.props.GetPosts();` gets the action, then `myPosts` gets the posts and converts into a state